# Block main thread, and wait for 5 other threads in a thread pool

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, pthreads

I have 11 threads: main, and 10 more in a Thread Pool. Let's imagine the main thread assigns works to 5 of the 10 threads, and now main needs to wait until they finish.

The problem is I can't just use pthread_join() because I don't know which 5 of the 10 threads are executing the works.

I am trying to use a Countdown Mechanism. Here's what I've tried:

```
typedef struct {
    int max; // Value to set the countdown at
    int count; // The count itself
    int ended; // Indicates how many threads have finished
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cWaitZero;
} CountDown;
```

I have the following functions:

```
void countdown_init (CountDown *countdown, int max) {
    countdown->max = max;
    countdown->count = max;
    countdown->ended = 0;

    pthread_mutex_init(&countdown->mutex, NULL);

    pthread_cond_init(&countdown->cWaitZero, NULL);
}

void countdown_destroy (CountDown *countdown) {
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&countdown->mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&countdown->cWaitZero);
}

void countdown_wait (CountDown *countdown) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&countdown->mutex);

    countdown->count--; // Countdown

    pthread_cond_broadcast(&countdown->cWaitZero); // Signal the other threads

    while (countdown->count > 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&countdown->cWaitZero, &countdown->mutex);
    }

    if (++countdown->ended == countdown->max) { // I want the last finishing thread to reset the countdown
        countdown_reset(countdown);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&countdown->mutex);
}

void countdown_reset(CountDown *countdown) {
    countdown->count = countdown->max;
}
```

In main:

```
// Create threadpool (10 threads) and shared buffer to put the works in
CountDown countdown;
countdown_init(&countdown, 5);
// Put 5 works in the shared buffer
```

In the threads work:

```
// Do all their work
countdown_wait(&countdown);

// Do some other stuff;
countdown_wait(&countdown); // I call this a second time, that's why I need to reset the countdown

return NULL;
```

However, this doesn't work. I tried debugging the value of countdown->count inside countdown_wait(), and it sometimes gets negative values. I don't see why.

Comment: In ISO C, you can use [`thrd_join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_join). If you are using POSIX Threads (your question does not have the "pthreads" tag though), then you can use [`pthread_join`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html).

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using a thread pool. I'm using POSIX threads, yes. Do you mind reading my edit?

Comment: When you say that `main` should wait until the 5 threads "finish", do you mean that `main` should wait until the 5 threads are finished with their work and are waiting for more work? Or do you mean that `main` should wait until the 5 threads have terminated? What do the worker threads do when they are finished with their work? Do they terminate or do they sleep until they are assigned more work?

Comment: You may want to use [condition variables](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) for the worker thread to signal the main thread when it has finished with a certain job.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to use condition variables now. I tried to implement them in a custom countdown mechanism. I updated my post, if you don't mind checking it out.

Comment: Are your worker threads already started when you create and initialize the `CountDown` object?

Comment: Since you stated that you couldn't use `pthread_join`, I suggested that you use condition variables instead, so that the worker thread signals the main thread using a condition variable that it has finished its work. According to this, the main thread should be calling `pthread_cond_wait` and (one of) the worker threads should be calling `pthread_cond_signal` to signal the main thread that the work is finished. However, in the code you posted, the main thread is not waiting on a condition variable. Instead, the worker threads are both signaling it and waiting on it. I don't understand this.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether the problem you describe is merely how to signal the main thread when a certain task is complete, or if the problem is in fact the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

Comment: 1) Yes, worker threads were already started; 2) I now understand condition variables better, and can see clearly the garbage I posted xD. I was trying to make main wait for the worker threads to finish their work. So yes, condition variables were the solution. The countdown mechanism was a method to count the threads that already finished. But it was not well implemented. It's working now, tho. The main problem was that I need to call countdown_wait() in main to, or else main will never wait for the threads.

Comment: Example: main initializes countdown with the value of 3. Then, assigns works to 2 threads, and immediately after, call countdown_wait() (to decrement the countdown and sleep). Before returning from the work, the threads call countdown_wait() as well, to decrement the countdown too. When countdown reaches 0, all threads asleep, wake up. 

If any of you would like, I can update the code in the post.